# Should the lateral force be applied above the C.o.G of an object lying on ground, to make it topple?

Tags: forces, experimental-physics

According to my understanding, if I apply a lateral force (parallel to the ground) on an object, standing on the ground, above it's center of gravity than the object topples over and won't start moving at all. However, if I apply the same amount of lateral force below its center of gravity then it won't topple over, instead will begin translating. This is explained in the figure below.

[image]

Can anyone just enlighten me the physics and reasoning behind it? Or if my observation and understanding is wrong? What factors can affect this toppling behavior of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By toppling here has to be understood **'rotating about the point $P$'** *When* this condition prevails is best illustrated by a FBD, so we can apply $N2L$:

[image: Object]

For there NOT to start rotation about $P$, acc. $N2L$ there has to be *no net torque acting on the object*.

We take the torques about $P$, as scalars and with CW to be positive and CCW to be negative:

$$F\times h-mg \times \frac{W}{2}\leq 0\tag{1}$$

(I've assumed the CoG projects to precisely half of the width $W$. If this is not the case the calculation has to be adjusted accordingly but the priciple still holds perfectly)

So we have:

$$h=\frac{mgW}{2F}$$

If $h < \frac{mgW}{2F}$ there's no start of rotation and no toppling but if $h > \frac{mgW}{2F}$ then the object will start toppling **provided the floor provides enough friction to prevent sliding (slipping)**.

The existence of a reactive force $F_N=mg$, originating from $P$ and pointing upwards, has been ignored here because it produces no torque about $P$ and thus plays no part in $(1)$.

Comment: So just to conclude, the general view that the toppling to take place if the force is applied above the C.o.G is wrong, right? It might also topple over if the force is below the C.o.G as well, right? Since for a material having a lower density but same mass, its C.o.G might shift up (if we keep the width the same) and even might go above the application of lateral force but toppling can still begin.

Comment: Yes, that is completely correct: it depends on ALL factors in $(1)$. Thanks for accepting the answer.